# Use customized font in iphone app, failed to launch the simulator!

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator, ios4

I want to apply my customized font in iPhone app. So I did as these steps,

1. add customized.ttf into Xcode project/Resources
2. add "Fonts provided by application" in plist with a pair of key/value like this - item 0/customized.ttf
3. update font of label's text like this - lable.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"customized" size:17];

But, it doesn't work... The simulator failed to launch. Am I wrong with any step? Could some friends help me about using customized font in iPhone app (support 3.x and 4)? Thanks in advance.

Linkou Bian
Email/MSN: linkou.bian@gmail.com

Comment: For a temp solution, I'm using FontLabel now. But I don't want to import lots of others classes into my tiny project. So, appreciated if pieces of code to solve this issue.